# Adding your own python project source code to site-packages folder using setuptools (setup.py install)

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm aware there are similar questions to such as this one, but I have trouble understanding how to actually automatically create module in site-packages for my own project.

I tried using `python setup.py install` and it created .egg file in my site-packages but I can't import it in simple python script.

I tried googling for about an hour now and the only solution I found is to directly copy the sources to a directory which I don't want to do as I'd have to copy it every time I change my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.

```
pip install .
```

Inside the project directory is actually giving me the wanted output, but problem is that I didn't nest the name of my package inside project.

Think, I have project foo, and I want to have imports such as:

```
from foo import bar
```

Well I had project named foo but I didn't have first package named foo rather I had straight away bar and all other packages, so that was the mistake.